# What is the maximum size of a video background?

Tags: video, html5-video, filesize

I am creating a website with a big video background. I have now created video files that are about 10 mb per 10 seconds of movie. But i am a little bit disapointed on the quality.

My target group are men 16-25 and most people will have a internetconnection about 6mb/s and up I am guessing.

So what is the safe filesize?

If you simple math you can calculate that if everyone has 6mb/s or better my movie could safely be around 2mb per secons resulting in a 10 second movie beeing 20mb is that a correct guessing.

Is that correct or is there a better way to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I haved tried for some months. It is safe to have your video size around 500kb/s - 1mb/s without having any loading trouble on modern computers.